# python dictionary function calls with self values

Tags: python, dictionary, user-defined-functions, element

In Python, how do I de-reference a dictionary's values in a call to a function referenced in that same dictionary?

For (silly) example:

```
def f1(x, y, z):
    return (x+y)/z

player = { 
    'x' : 0,
    'y' : 22,
    'z' : -37,
    'f' : f1(self.x, self.y, self.z)
}
```

I know can do this with classes. Sure. But, can do this with dictionaries?

Comment: You can not, since all key and value expressions are first resolved before a dictionary is constructed. So you can not reference a value from a dictionary before it is created. Furthermore most languages have some special keyword like `this` or `self`. Python has not. It is only because of the meta-class that `self` is "injected" properly. Most people see `__init__` as a constructor, but it is possible through metaclasses to omit the `__init__`. At the point `__init__` is constructed, the instance is already constructed.

Comment: I don't get the question. I must be tried.

Comment: @JeanFrancoisFabre: SaraToo wants to obtain th value associated with the `'x'` key when constructing the value for `'f'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that inside a literal because while the literal is evaluated the dictionary doesn't exist (yet). So there's no way to refer to it.

However, you can insert it later:

```
>>> player = { 'x' : 0, 'y' : 22, 'z' : -37}
>>> player['f'] = f1(player['x'], player['y'], player['z'])
>>> player
{'f': -0.5945945945945946, 'x': 0, 'y': 22, 'z': -37}
```

Or in case it should be dynamic, you could use a wrapper. For example a `lambda` function:

```
>>> player = { 'x' : 0, 'y' : 22, 'z' : -37}
>>> player['f'] = lambda: f1(player['x'], player['y'], player['z'])
>>> player['f']()
-0.5945945945945946
>>> player['x'] = 10
>>> player['f']()
-0.8648648648648649
>>> player['x'] = 100
>>> player['f']()
-3.2972972972972974
```

But I guess just making `Player` a class would be more readable and easier to maintain. Also classes make that sort of thing almost trivial without needing `lambda`s or such like.

Answer (score 0):

def f1(x, y, z):
        return (x+y)/z

l = [10, 4, 7, f1]

l[3](l[0], l[1], l[2])